# Create a boolean mask for a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 3D numpy array of size [2000x7200x40] (we will call it precip) that I would like to mask out certain values (-9999) to be excluded from a `scipy.mstats.rankdata(precip,axis=2,use_missing=False)` classification.

Think of the data like:

```
[-9999, 2, 3, 5, -9999
       4, 7, -9999, 6]...
```

I have largely been unsuccessful in doing so; it seems most `np.ma` functions such as `np.ma.masked_invalid` only apply along a 1-D array.

-9999 values may be different for each array in the time series (z).

I have tried numpy functions such as:

```
 #mask the -9999 values out
   mask = np.empty_like(precip)
   mask = ~(precip == -9999).all(axis=2,keepdims=True)
```

and then broadcasting this to a 3-D array with `mask = [numpy.newaxis,:,:]`

However this results in a 2000x7200x1 array, which then throws a dimension error when multiplied by precip because it's expecting an array of dimension 40.

Is there some simple function or bit of code that I have overlooked that will easily do this for me? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use masked multi-dimensional arrays. However, you must ensure that your mask and data are the same size.

```
>>> mask = ~(precip == -9999).all(axis=2, keepdims=True)
>>> mask.shape
(2000, 7200, 1)
>>> repeated_mask = np.repeat(mask, precip.shape[-1], axis=-1) # Ensure same shape
>>> repeated_mask.shape == precip.shape
True
>>> ma = np.ma.masked_array(precip, mask=repeated_mask)
>>> ma.shape == precip.shape
True
```

Note that you can also multiply the mask by the original data array without issue, as long as you don't add an *additional* axis with `np.newaxis`. The `keepdims=True` argument to `np.all` means that the number of dimensions is the same, and so `mask` can directly be multiplied with `precip` due to [Numpy's broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) mechanisms. For example:

```
>>> mask = ~(precip == -9999).all(axis=2, keepdims=True)
>>> mask.shape
(2000, 7200, 1)
>>> (precip * mask).shape == precip.shape # `mask` will be broadcast to the shape of `precip`
True
```

Comment: I believe this gets me very close; however outside of a np.ma function it just replaced everything with zero. It looks like I need to replace -9999 or np.nan values with '--' as an np.ma mask on the original input data so that scipy will ignore those values in the ranking. I am unsure of how to then apply that to the 3D array - most mask functions seem to only work on a single 2D array - without inserting another for loop into the code. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, I ended up completely abandoning the mstats ranking method; it balks when an entire row is masked out apparently.

I ended up using the above masking code: 
       `mask = ~(precip == -9999).all(axis=2, keepdims=True)`

after a `apply_along_axis(lambda a: scipy.stats.ranking(a), axis=2, precip))` method

Then just `ranks = ranks*mask` did the trick to mask out the values that were always -9999 in the precipitation data.

Hopefully this helps someone confused with `mstats.ranking` spitting back an 0-D array error in the future.  The scipy.stats.ranking module also seems to be MUCH quicker than the scipy.mstats.ranking module as an added bonus.